# Converting a binary value to hexadecimal in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, hex

I have a situation where I need to convert a binary value to hex in Ruby. My situation is as follows:

When `bin = "0000111"`, my output should be: `hex = "07"`.

When `bin = "010001111"`, my output should be: `hex = "08f"`.

Could someone help me out on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
>> "0x%02x" % "0000111".to_i(2) #=> "0x07"
>> "0x%02x" % "010001111".to_i(2) #=> "0x8f"
```

Edit: if you don't want the output to be `0x..` but just `0..` leave out the first `x` in the format string.

Comment: when i pass in '1' a single binary bit, this converts to 001. Shouldn't it convert to '1' in hex as well?

Comment: ```
("0%02x" % binary.to_i(2)) #=> "001"

Comment: `"0x%02x"%"1".to_i(2) #=> "0x01"`.

Answer (score 11):

```
def bin_to_hex(s)
    s.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16).rjust(2,'0') }.join
end
```

Which I found here (with zero padding modifications):

http://anthonylewis.com/2011/02/09/to-hex-and-back-with-ruby/

Comment: I don't know how people claim it works! For me, using ruby 4.1, it gives: `'1111'.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join
=> "31313131"` (And I want `"f"` or something similiar.)

Comment: @Djunzu You're talking about something different. The string `'1111'` has four bytes, and each has a value of 49 (ie, the ASCII value). 49 in decimal is 31 in hex. You don't have a "binary" value in the sense that the question is talking about. You have a string containing ASCII characters `'1'` and `'0'`.

Comment: @Djunzu Actually, nevermind. I just realized that actually, you're right, and the answer is using "binary" in the wrong sense.

Answer (score 5):

Both `String#to_i` and `Integer#to_s` take an optional integer argument specifying the base. So you can convert your binary string to an integer using base 2 and then convert that integer back to a string using base 16.

Comment: hey thanks for ur response.. As u say if i use "11111".to_i(2).to_s(16) it gives me "1f" but if i give "01111".to_i(2).to_s(16) it gives me  only "f" but i want "0f"

Comment: @sundar: You can using `String#%` (a.k.a. `sprintf`) instead of `to_s` to format the number appropriately - using `%02x` to format the number as a hexadecimal number padded to 2 digits using 0s. However this does not work if you want a base other than 16 (or 10 if you use `d` instead of `x`), as `%` does not allow you to pick an arbitrary base. Alternatively you can use `to_s` followed by `String#rjust`, which works with arbitrary bases and padding characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `unpack` method on string pointing the target to be hex

```rb
def bin_to_hex(binary_string)
  binary_string.unpack('H*').first
end
```

Refer to: https://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack

I found it to be much more clean than the solutions listed above.

Answer (score 0):

as state above by @Michael Kohl easiest way, define method with the action

```
  # if you don't want the output to be 0x.. but just 0.. leave out the first x in the format string.
  def self.bin_to_hex(string)
    "0x%02x" % "#{string}".to_i(2)
  end
```

and use the method like this

```
string = "00011110"
puts bin_to_hex(string)
=> 0x1e
```

remember these are still ASCII representations, in case you want to encode it and send bytes as HEX (send via UDP or low level protocols) just do:

```
value = self.bin_to_hex(value)
bytes = [value]
bytes.pack('H*' * bytes.size)
```